# Writing data from python returns gibberish

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to read a folder of text files and combine them into a single (wide) file (comma or tab delimited). My issues is that the line feeds (or carriage returns) are showing up in some sort of weird format.

Input data Example: (I have included the end of line characters)

```
Directional Deformation (in)[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
0.[CR][LF]
```

Output when I combine several input data:

```
Directional Deformation (in)Ｌ䓾椀爀攀挀琀椀漀渀愀氀 䐀攀昀漀爀洀愀琀椀漀渀 ⠀椀渀⤀Ⰰ﻿Directional Deformation (in)ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
0.,0.,0.ബ਍ⰀⰀⰀ഍[LF]
```

I have been working to find the correct combination of encoding and read/wite settings but not luck so far. Example code below:

```
import glob
import os

# Determine the number of row in data file
tmpFiles = [open(f) for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]
nRows = sum(not line.isspace() for line in tmpFiles[0])

# fetch the file names
files = [open(f, 'r') for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]

# Combine data file columns
fout = open ("results.dat", 'w')
for row in range(1, nRows):
    for f in files:
        fout.write(f.readline().strip())
        fout.write(',')
    fout.write(os.linesep) # Not sure if this should be '\n' or ???
fout.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does each file look like? Also  `files = [open(f, 'r') for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]` it looks like you never close these files.

Comment: os.linesep is OS dependant. It is [LF] on Unix and [CR][LF] on Windows. So I guess you are running your script on a Linux or Mac Os, the file you read is a Windows file, but python handles it for you

Comment: You don't need your nbRows computation and the associated for loop. It is what cause your garbage at the end of lines

Comment: I must use the nRows loop else I will only perform the merge on the first row. I'm running this on windows. I believe this is some sort of binary issue. When I open and write in binary mode the results file is written correctly but I struggle with double spacing and other issues causing a other malformations.

Comment: Opening and closing a single file with binary read/write works perfectly... I just need to figure out how to push commas and LR in a binary format.

Answer (score 1):

OK... I have this working. Using codecs in binary read and write modes the output file is created with the correct format (no gibberish). Note that it was also encoded as utf-16 (although python reported cp1252 which I am assuming was the gibberish output).

The input files are ANSYS results output files written with the (right click) 'Export Text File' in the ANSYS solution results. The code to merge the individual results files is shown below:

```
import os
import glob
import codecs

# Path and file settings
path = 'C:\\temp\\'

# Determine the number of row in data file
# [must request in binary mode for correct count]
tmpFiles = [open(f, 'rb') for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]
nRows = sum(not line.isspace() for line in tmpFiles[0])

# Read individual results files 
files = [codecs.open(f, 'rb', encoding='utf-16') for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]
with codecs.open(path + 'results.dat', 'wb', encoding='utf-16') as fout:
    for row in range(1, nRows):
        for f in files: 
            fout.write(f.readline().strip())
            fout.write(',')
        fout.write(os.linesep)
fout.close()
```

The output file now looks like the following for three results files in the temp folder: (I need to get rid of the last comma...)

```
Directional Deformation (in),Directional Deformation (in),Directional Deformation (in),
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
0.,0.,0.,
```

Thanks for the help... regards